# how to convert gray to color image in cv2 python

Tags: python, opencv

i use cv2 python in low-pass-FFt and i already change attribute of image but this image is gray image . i want to change it to color image and keep attribute of gray image

```
----------
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


img = cv2.imread('rocket.jpg', 0)
height, width = img.shape

plt.figure("Input")
plt.subplot(221),plt.imshow(img, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Input Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

fft = np.log(np.abs(np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(img))))
plt.subplot(222),plt.imshow(fft, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Fourier Transform'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

r = 200
h_Filter_Low_Pass = np.zeros(img.size, img.dtype).reshape(img.shape)
for icounter in range(1, height):
    for jcounter in range(1, width):
        if ((height/2-icounter)**2 + (width/2 - jcounter)**2)**0.5 < r:
            h_Filter_Low_Pass[icounter, jcounter] = 1
plt.subplot(223),plt.imshow(h_Filter_Low_Pass, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Filter'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

h_fft = (np.abs(np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(h_Filter_Low_Pass)))+1)
plt.subplot(224),plt.imshow(h_fft, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Fourier Transform (Filter)'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

fshift = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(img))


plt.figure("output")
new = fshift * (h_Filter_Low_Pass)
g_ifft1 = (np.abs(np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(new)).real))



plt.subplot(),plt.imshow(g_ifft1, cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('output'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of lines:

```
fshift = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(img))
new = fshift * (h_Filter_Low_Pass)
g_ifft1 = (np.abs(np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(new)).real))

plt.subplot(),plt.imshow(g_ifft1, cmap = 'gray')
```

You might want to use:

```
img_color = cv2.imread('rocket.jpg')
b,g,r = cv2.split(img_color)
def g_ifft(x):
    fshift = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(x))
    new = fshift * (h_Filter_Low_Pass)
    g_ifft1 = (np.abs(np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(new)).real))
    g_ifft1 = cv2.normalize(g_ifft1,None,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8U)
    return g_ifft1
b,g,r = map(g_ifft, (b,g,r))
g_ifft1 = cv2.merge((b,g,r))

g_ifft1 = cv2.cvtColor(g_ifft1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

plt.subplot(),plt.imshow(g_ifft1)
```

This will split your image into color channels, apply your filter separately to each color channel and then merge them again. (Normalization step is needed to convert the array from `float64` to `uint8` type before merging.)

Example output:

[image: Dnipro rocker, Fourier transform, mask]

[image: Dnipro rocket with Fourier transform applied]

Comment: in function g_ifft(x) it has parameter x but you don't put the parameter in function and function how it know what picture do you use?

Comment: Function `g_ifft` is applied to sequence `(b,g,r)` by built in `map` function. Read the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map

Comment: Welcome! Please, set my answer as "Best answer".